# WP_Query filter by custom meta

Tags: filters, users, query

I try to make a page to list users with a meta values.

I search to get all users with a site url or user_description
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a meta query using `OR` relation. After that you use `get_users()` function to get all the users you selected in the query. Then output their nicename in a list with using `foreach`.

```
$your_url = 'https://www.yoururl.com';
$your_description = 'your description';

$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'user_url',
        'value'   => $your_url,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'description',
        'value'   => $your_description,
        'compare' => '='
    )
)
);
$users_array = get_users($args);
echo '<ul>';
if ($users_array ) {
  foreach ($users_array as $user) {
    echo '<li>'.$user->user_nicename.'</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
} else {
  echo 'nothing found';
}
```

---

Another way would be to loop through all users, check the meta values and only output the name, if the value fits. The disadvantage is that you have to go through all users, which can take some time if you have a lot of them. So I just add this as an addition, but would recommend using the meta query.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

```
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID','user_url','user_nicename','description' ) ) );
foreach($users as $user){
    $userurl = get_user_meta ( $user->user_url)); // all the values you need
    if ( $userurl == $your_url ) { echo $user->user_nicename.'<br>'; }
    // and so on
}
```

---

**EDIT because of comment:**

You can order by a meta_key with adding it to your $args array:

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'user_url',
        'value'   => $your_url,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'description',
        'value'   => $your_description,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
),
'orderby' => 'user_url'
);
```

This will work for all kind of fields, you just need the meta_key and the order_by. Here is a nice article of how to use it: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'license_id',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value'
);
```

You are also able to choose ASC or DESC order:

```
'orderby' => array(
        'license_id' => 'ASC'
    ),
```

Comment: I think I’ve spoken badly. I created a license_id field, for members of group. I want to display all users with a license, and sort users by license_id. I can see the list of users, but I don’t sort it. 
Thx

Comment: I added how to "orderby" in my answer, please check if it solves your issue.

Comment: Nice thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$your_url = 'https://www.yoururl.com';
$your_description = 'your description';

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'user_url',
            'value'   => $your_url,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'description',
            'value'   => $your_description,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

$users_array = get_users( $args );

if ( $users_array ) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ( $users_array as $user ) {
        echo '<li>' . $user->user_nicename . '</li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo 'nothing found';
}
```